# How to display the name of an uploaded zip file without using the event.target in vue/javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an input that accepts type of file and accepts zip files to be specific. I want to display the name of the zip file once it is uploaded in the associated input label dynamically. Right now I can retrieve the name of the file using a method but it requires the `event` from the input. This is failing when trying to render the file name dynamically as I get this error:

```
app.js:164890 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined"
```

If I pass the `e` when calling `{{fileName(e)}}` then I get this error

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "e" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property
```

This is my HTML tag:

```
<input
   id="zip"
   name="zip"
   type="file"
   accept="application/zip"
   required>
          
   <label for="zip">{{fileName()}}</label>
```

Vue method

```
fileName(e) {
      return e.target.files[0].name ? return e.target.files[0].name : 'Choose File';
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to the `change` event of the input via an [Event Handler](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers) and retrieve the filename every time the user selects a file.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
      fileName: "Choose File",
  },
  methods: {
      fileSelected: function(e){
          this.fileName = e.target.files[0].name;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<input
   id="zip"
   name="zip"
   type="file"
   accept="application/zip"
   required
   v-on:change="fileSelected">
          
   <label for="zip">{{fileName}}</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I was missing, thank you @Prerak Sola

Comment: Happy to help :)